# Pre Tag in HTML

Tags: html, pre

So I am just learning to HTML , as I wanted to become a web developer.
I used the `<pre>` tag for the proper alignment in my code.
But the alignment seems to come little fuzzy.

But the output of 3 and 4 i.e Reason to live and Happiness are not properly align with respect to the above quotes.

```
<p>For me you are:</p>
<pre>
                    1.Love
                    2.Life
                    3.Reason to Live
                    4.Happiness
            </pre>
```

Comment: I've edited your code to so that it's correctly formatted as code, can you double check that it accurately  matches the code from your web site? Incidentally, if you want to create a numbered list then consider using  the - semantic - [`<ol>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol).

Comment: you should not rely on the `<pre>` tag like that. Try to learn some CSS. It's useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested your code and it seems to line up fine, you could always put the content in a list like the below:

```
<ol>
 <li>Love</li>
 <li>Life</li>
 <li>Reason to Live</li>
 <li>Happiness</li>
</ol>
```

If this isn't what you need, please could you show us how it appears for you?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_html_editor.php
Kindly check what I mean.
The 4 and 5 point are not align why so ?

Comment: Unfortunately i can't see your code as it's the tutorial site, please create a fiddle link here https://jsfiddle.net/ and send us the link when you've saved it

Comment: The reason it doesn't line up is because you have the content wrapped in a <center> tag, try putting this on the pre tag: style="text-align: left;"

Comment: Alternatively, you can just type in P tags the content rather than putting them in a <pre> or <ol>

Comment: But can you tell me , even if it was wrapped in center tag , why didn't it work.
I mean we centered the whole code , and then applied <pr> tag , it should work
as first two points worked correctly

Comment: Personally i wouldn't recommend using the pre tags and i would go with using <ol> or putting them in a <p> as that way when you center the content, it won't have it's own alignment to go against, the <pre> is aligning itself based on the other content, so it will not be in line with the above.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code, it works fine

[image]

You can share how it appears in your machine.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_html_editor.php
You can check here , What is wrong ?

Comment: can't see your code, as suggested by @Jenko, share a jsfiddle or ideone link

Comment: edited your code see it here https://jsfiddle.net/n8rwzvg5/ or you can just use the @Jenko version